# Copying data from gateway node to a different cluster in same network

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, scp, distcp

Is there a way to copy data from Gateway node in Cluster1  directly to HDFS of Cluster 2 when in same network.Currently I am doing scp to gateway node of Cluster 2 and uploading data to HDFS.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
hadoop fs -put [local_file] hdfs://[namenode2]:[namenode2_port]/[path]
```

Assuming:

- [local_file] is the file in gateway node in cluster 1
- [namenode2] is the namenode of cluster 2
- [namenode2_port] is the namenode port of cluster 2
- [path] is the path in hdfs to put the file

Comment: Currently I am getting connection refused when I use the above command. Is there a different command to run this?

Comment: :hadoop fs -ls hdfs://[namenode2]:[port]/ . So, I get a Connection refused message when I do this command.

Comment: Could you telnet for the port,and check whether the port is open